# Setting a string value to a variable

Tags: batch-file

I need to set a variable to a substring I get from a find command, but it is returning the command

```
findstr /is "CouId:" C:\dev\AssayInfo.txt
set number=findstr /is "CouId:" C:\dev\AssayInfo.txt
echo %number% 
pause
```

This is what the file that I'm using findstr looks like:

```
Protocol: NVD_RCP_Fluidic_Accuracy_v0.4
ProtocolVersion: 1
SampleId: FLQC+20191126+00111280+96
InstrumentId: 123456789001
CouId: 138527011
CouSlot: 1
```

The variable should have the value `138527011` in this case.

Comment: Ok, here we go again. :) to set the variable is not the issue, you wanted to perform other items when variable is found...anyway, you just want the variable? THen if so, I can do that for you.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard , yes, but  after getting the variable i was going to use IF statements to make comparisons. I am felling like i am just wasting your time, but do  you have any tips of how i should solve this?

Comment: For those wishing to see the previously deleted question, _(and who can)_, it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54705011).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=: " %%i in ('type "C:\dev\AssayInfo.txt" ^| findstr /i CouID') do set "number=%%j"
echo %number%
:# Here you can add your if statements etc.
pause
```

Note, that this is exactly what you required, as per this question and not the other question and therefore this is all I can give you now.

However, this is not even needed, you can do it without the `set` variable:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=: " %%i in ('type "C:\dev\AssayInfo.txt" ^| findstr /i CouID') do (
   echo %%i
   :# Here you can add your if statements etc.
)
pause
```

Comment: thank you, but for some reason im getting "the system could not find the file specified"

Comment: change your path in the for loop to `C:\dev\AssayInfo.txt`

Comment: I updated the answer with your path, copy as is and try.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use:

```bat
@echo off

for /F "tokens=2" %%A IN ('findstr /ibc:"CouId: " C:\dev\AssayInfo.txt') do set "num=%%A"

rem Do some code here:

pause
exit /b 0
```

which is much shorter.

Note that direct comparisons can be done directly inside the `for` loop like:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=2" %%A IN ('findstr /ibc:"CouId: " C:\dev\AssayInfo.txt') do (
    set "num=%%A"
    rem Do sum comparisons with '!num!', not '%num%'!:
)
pause
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

Comment: Using type here reminds me at the [Useless Use of Cat Award](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) ;-) `for /F "tokens=2" %%A IN ('findstr /ibc:"CouId: " C:\dev\AssayInfo.txt') do set "num=%%A"`

Comment: There are situations, where `type` is neccessary: when processing Unicode files (test with `wmic bios get serialnumber >test.txt` and both `for /f %a in ('findstr "[a-z]" test.txt') do @echo %a` and `for /f %a in ('type test.txt^|findstr "[a-z]"') do @echo %a`)