# Findstr within a ("variable")folder

Tags: batch-file

I am pretty new at programming in batch files, and stack overflow users have being a lot of help. My problem is almost solved. Now there is only one thing that is missing to make my script work is.

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=: " %%i in ('type "C:\dev\1597\AssayInfo.txt" ^| findstr /i CouID') do set "number=%%j"
echo %number%
```

in this part of the code i need to be able to find the AssayInfo.txt without the folder 1597. In my case i will have a lot of folders with random generated numbers and all of them have a Assayinfo.txt, but if i try to run the code without the 1597 path it just say that could not find the file.

Comment: 1. There's no need to use `type`, simply use the file as a parameter of`the `findstr` command, like `findstr /I "CouID" "C:\dev\1597\AssayInfo.txt"`. 2. Wrap around a loop `for /D %%j in ("C:\dev\*") do` to find the directory containing your text file, then further use `C:\dev\%%~j\AssayInfo.txt`...

Comment: @aschipfl if possible, could you give me an exemple how this would work?

Comment: [déjà vu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54711447/setting-a-string-value-to-a-variable)

Comment: And once again, for those who can see it, [double déjà vu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54705011/6738015)!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a string value to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54711447/setting-a-string-value-to-a-variable)

Comment: as you have "a lot of" `C:\dev\*\AssayInfo.txt`, how to know, which one to take? (did I guess your intention correctly?)

Comment: @Stephan yes, got some folders at dev, and them all have the AssayInfo.txt, in that AssayInfo there is a serial number that is the same name of a folder that i need to sent that AssayInfo.txt to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We kind of went through these already, but anyway:

To actually set it as a variable after file was found.:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%i in ('dir /s /b /a-d AssayInfo.txt') do (
  for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('type "%%~fi" ^| findstr /i "CouID"') do set "number=%%a"
    echo Found number !number! in file "%%~fi"
)
```

Comment: @Itwasme Hmmm for? :)

Comment: Hmm, my very first hint in the deleted question was to use findstr with the /s option what avoids the `dir /b/s` and the also the type. @joao seems quite indecisive.

Comment: @LotPings yes, findstr with the search option does avoid the type and dir, the only reason I do this is because if there are 1000s of other files, findstr takes quite a long time to search each until it finds a match.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard hey, i am really grateful for all the help you gave me, i know this question wasn't the best formulated one, but you nailed it. hope someday i can re-tribute your kindness!

Comment: No problems at all @joao